# AWS Cloud Formation Stuck in Review_In_Progress

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I was trying to set up AWS Code Pipeline with AWS SAM for Lambda using Java-8 as mentioned in the documentations

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html
(example is in node.js though).

However, my Staging is stuck at CloudFormation Stack is stuck in REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS for a long time. Is there any way to debug this issue?

I don't see any further events coming in console. Is there any specific things to check for?

The template is as follow

```
$ aws codepipeline get-pipeline --region us-east-1 --name aws-lexbot-facebook-pipeline
{
    "pipeline": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/AWS-CodePipeline-Service", 
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [], 
                        "name": "Source", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source", 
                            "owner": "ThirdParty", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "GitHub"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyApp"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "Owner": “xxxxxxx”, 
                            "Repo": "lexbot", 
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "true", 
                            "Branch": "master", 
                            "OAuthToken": "****"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Build", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyApp"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "name": "CodeBuild", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "CodeBuild"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyAppBuild"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "aws-lexbot-facebook-codebuild"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Staging", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyAppBuild"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "name": "LexBotBetaStack", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "CloudFormation"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_REPLACE", 
                            "ChangeSetName": "LexBotChangeSet", 
                            "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/cloudformation-lambda-execution-role", 
                            "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM", 
                            "StackName": "LexBotBetaStack", 
                            "TemplatePath": "MyAppBuild::SamTemplate.yaml"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3", 
            "location": “XXXXXX-us-east-1-987802409920"
        }, 
        "name": "aws-lexbot-facebook-pipeline", 
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CodePipeline steps?

Comment: Hi.. I edited the post with the template

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Overview**

In your CodePipeline step, you're using the `CHANGE_SET_CREATE` action mode. This creates a change set on the CloudFormation Stack, but does not automatically execute it. You would need a second action that executes the change set using `CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE`. Alternatively, you can change the action mode on your action to `CREATE_UPDATE` which should directly update your action.

One reason you might want to use `CHANGE_SET_CREATE` and `CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE` in CodePipeline, is if you want to have an approval step between them. If you are expecting this to be completed automatically, I'd recommend `CREATE_UPDATE`.

**CREATE_UPDATE example**

Below is your CodePipeline **Staging** stage, but using `CREATE_UPDATE` instead of `CREATE_CHANGE_SET`. This creates a new stack named stack, or updates the existing one if one with that name already exists.

```
{
    "inputArtifacts": [
        {
            "name": "MyAppBuild"
        }
    ], 
    "name": "LexBotBetaStack", 
    "actionTypeId": {
        "category": "Deploy", 
        "owner": "AWS", 
        "version": "1", 
        "provider": "CloudFormation"
    }, 
    "outputArtifacts": [], 
    "configuration": {
        "ActionMode": "CREATE_UPDATE", 
        "ChangeSetName": "LexBotChangeSet", 
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/cloudformation-lambda-execution-role", 
        "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM", 
        "StackName": "LexBotBetaStack", 
        "TemplatePath": "MyAppBuild::SamTemplate.yaml"
    }, 
    "runOrder": 1
}
```

**CHANGE_SET_CREATE and CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE example**

Below is an example of how you could use `CHANGE_SET_CREATE` and `CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE` together. It first creates a change set, on the named stack, then executes that change set. It's really useful if you want to have a CodePipeline Approval step between the change set, and executing it, so you can review the intended changes.

```
{
    "inputArtifacts": [
        {
            "name": "MyAppBuild"
        }
    ], 
    "name": "LexBotBetaStackChangeSet", 
    "actionTypeId": {
        "category": "Deploy", 
        "owner": "AWS", 
        "version": "1", 
        "provider": "CloudFormation"
    }, 
    "outputArtifacts": [], 
    "configuration": {
        "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_REPLACE", 
        "ChangeSetName": "LexBotChangeSet", 
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/cloudformation-lambda-execution-role", 
        "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM", 
        "StackName": "LexBotBetaStack", 
        "TemplatePath": "MyAppBuild::SamTemplate.yaml"
    }, 
    "runOrder": 1
},
{
    "name": "LexBotBetaStackExecute", 
    "actionTypeId": {
        "category": "Deploy", 
        "owner": "AWS", 
        "version": "1", 
        "provider": "CloudFormation"
    }, 
    "configuration": {
        "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE", 
        "ChangeSetName": "LexBotChangeSet", 
        "StackName": "LexBotBetaStack", 
    }, 
    "runOrder": 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I tried both. The first (CREATE_UPDATE) dint work. But adding a second execute step worked.

Comment: Cool, if this fixes your problem, want to mark it as accepted? That way people with similar issues can more reliably find the answer

Comment: I just did accept that answer. Thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 11):

I went to the change set and hit the execute button so it now shows CREATION_IN_PROGRESS.

Answer (score 6):

Some one has already answered, but for more clarity, Please refer below screenshot. Click on Change Sets and then select the change set and hit Execute.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, just the answer I needed. Day saved :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to some service bug in your template file/troposphere code. Make sure you can visualize the cf tree to check how the services communicate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).