# How to fix 'WaiterUnrecoverableException' when using the Jenkins SAM plugin to build a serverless app

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-plugins, aws-sam

I have a very simple Jenkins job that builds and then deploys a step function to AWS. I have been able to build and deploy from my desktop using the SAM cli no problem. However, when I set up jenkins to do it I get the following error:

> ERROR: Build step failed with exception
>   com.amazonaws.waiters.WaiterUnrecoverableException: Resource never entered 
>   the desired state as it failed.

The stack gets created in AWS and stays in REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS. I'm assuming that the 'Waiter' is waiting for the stack to enter another state. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394040/aws-cloud-formation-stuck-in-review-in-progress) but it doesn't help very much.

Through the SAM CLI I can package and deploy just fine with

```
sam package --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket thebucketofjesse
sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name jesse-stack-6 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region us-west-1
```

EDIT

I think I may have discovered the cause of this issue. I stopped using the SAM plugin and instead created a batch script to run the SAM commands manually. Everything worked except for some reason 'sam package' isn't adding the S3 uri to the yaml template output. So when it runs 'sam deploy' it looks at the output template and expects an S3 uri. It then fails and leaves the stack in REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS state.

When I run the above commands in the cli manually it will upload my state-machine.yaml file to S3 and the resulting packaged.yaml cloudformation template will have the S3 uri.

template.yaml

[image: template.yaml]

packaged.yaml
[image: packaged.yaml]

When I run the sam commands in jenkins the S3 uri is not in packaged.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So there seems to be an issue with the sam package command.

In my **template.yaml** file I am specifying the definition of my step function in an external file called state-machine.yaml (If you don't know how to do that go [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/531)). In the template.yaml file it looks like this

```
Resources:
  ClosedCaptionStateMachine:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      RoleArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - ClosedCaptionStateMachineRole
        - Arn
      Fn::Transform:
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:            
          Location: 'state-machine.yaml'
```

When I run `sam package` it is supposed to upload the **state-machine.yaml** file to an S3 bucket and then insert the S3 uri into the resulting yaml output file which I named **packaged.yaml**. It looks like this

```
Resources:
  ClosedCaptionStateMachine:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      RoleArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - ClosedCaptionStateMachineRole
        - Arn
      Fn::Transform:
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:
          Location: s3://thebucketofjesse/ba638c2815c6a4d4ad93c5bb5e3c4f32
```

However, for some reason it was not putting the S3 uri in **packaged.yaml**. Instead it kept it as **state-machine.yaml**. So when I ran `sam deploy` it would look for the S3 uri but not find it.

So what's the fix?

Well I discovered, purely by chance, that if you run `sam package` from outside the directory that **template.yaml** is located in and use full paths, it doesn't put the S3 uri in **packaged.yaml**. So you have to run `sam package` from the directory that **template.yaml** is located in and use relative paths.