# Cloudformation - recreating stack with a previously used name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a pipeline.yaml file that creates 3 stacks for me:

1. backend-ci
2. backend-staging
3. backend-prod

The backend-ci and backend-staging stacks get created successfully but the backend-prod does not. My hunch is that it's not being created due to the fact that I've created a stack previously by the same name.  The stack gets stuck in the REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS status and never moves forward. Further, I have zero insight into the reason this is happening because there are no entries in the stack's Events.

Am I correct to think that this is because I've created a stack previously by the same name?  If so, how can I confirm this?  That is, is there another AWS service I should be using that will show me my error?  Lastly, how do I get past this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you goto the console and then change set and hit the execute button . Plus if the stack is not important you can simply delete it and you can recreate it. You are right there if you cant have two stacks with same name. [AWS Cloud Formation Stuck in Review_In_Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407316/2246345)

Comment: Yes!  That was it.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment this issue got resolved by

> by executing the changeset manually from the cloudformation console.

As described in this post [AWS Cloud Formation Stuck in Review_In_Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52388436/2246345)